# Observing Artefacts along azimuth direction after applying RMA to FMCW radar data

Tags: signal-analysis, radar

I have simulated 3 scatterers for FMCW radar signal processing using Range Migration Algorithm.

Background:
The Range Migration algorithm steps are as follows:

1. Applying Azimuth FFT on the raw data
2. Apply "Matched Filter"
3. Apply "Stolt Interpolation"
4. Apply 2D Inverse Fourier Transform on the resulting signal

Signal Model:

Starting Signal dechirped signal model with RVP term removed,

[image]

After Azimuth Fourier Transform,

[image]

What I am observing

[image: Final Image Generated After Applying the RMA Algorithm using FMCW Radar]

What I should be observing:

[image: Final Image Generated After Applying the RMA Algorithm using Pulsed Radar]

Y-axis : Azimuth direction
X-axis : Range direction

**Question:**

So it seems the scatterer in the final image is diffused along the azimuth direction? But I am not sure what might be causing this diffusion along the azimuth axis. Could someone suggest what I should be looking out for? In terms of system parameters ? Or it might be due a step I am performing incorrectly? A few potential directions to look at is very much appreciated.

*The following code is meant for someone who wants to advice on how to tackle the signal processing problem without actually having to implement the code from scratch*

*Data generation code for reference:*

```
c = 3e8 # speed of light constant 
B = 3.6e9 # Bandwidth
pr = c/2/B # range resolution

PRF = 2500/3 # Pulse repetition frequency
PRI = 1/PRF # Pulse repetition Interval
Tp = PRI # Pulse width
Cr = B/Tp # Chirp rate

Fc = 3.48*1e10 # Center frequency
Fs = 25e6 # system sampling rate 
ts = 1/Fs # sampling interval

Nrg = round(Fs * Tp) # Number of range samples
t = np.linspace(-Nrg/2,Nrg/2,Nrg)*ts # Fast time 

radarVel = np.array([4,0,0]) # speed of aircraft in m/s
pa =  0.054 # azimuth resolution

# Derieved Parameters
Rs = 118 # slant distance to scene center
lamC = c/Fc # wavelength
delTh = (lamC)/(2*pa) # integration angle
L = Rs*delTh/sin(np.deg2rad(90)) # Synthetic Aperture Length (2.21)
Ta = L/eucDist(radarVel) # Synthetic Aperture time (2.22)
Naz = round(PRF * Ta /2) * 2  #Number of Azimuth samples (matter of convenience)

tSeq = np.arange(0,Naz) * PRI # timings

H = 34
radarPosc = np.array([0,np.sqrt((Rs**2)-(H**2)),H])# Radar Coords at Aperture center along the path
radarPoss = radarPosc - (radarVel * Naz//2 * PRI) # Radar's Starting Position


radarSeq = np.zeros((3,len(tSeq)))
radarSeq[0,:] = radarPoss[0] + tSeq * radarVel[0]
radarSeq[1,:] = radarPoss[1] + tSeq * radarVel[1]
radarSeq[2,:] = radarPoss[2] + tSeq * radarVel[2]

# Data generation
raw = np.zeros((Naz,Nrg), dtype=np.complex_)

KR = (4*pi/c)*(Fc+Cr*t) # Kr Spatial frequency (3.11)

for n in range(Naz):
    for scat in scattererCoords:

        R  = np.sqrt((radarSeq[1,n]-scat[1])**2 + (radarSeq[2,n]-scat[2])**2)
        x_comp = radarSeq[0,n]-scat[0] + norm(radarVel)*t # includes the motion between the pulses
        phase = np.exp(1j*KR*np.sqrt(R**2 + x_comp**2)) # without RVP term
        tau = 2*np.sqrt(R**2 + x_comp**2)/c 
        raw[n,:] += rect(t,Tp,tau) * phase
```

**Range Migration Algorithm Procedure**

```
# # 1D FT along azimuth track
S = fftshift(fft(raw, axis=0),axes=0)

# # Matched Filtering
phi_mf = -Rs*KYY   # Matched Filter
S_mf = S * np.exp(1j*phi_mf)

# Stolt interpolation
kstart = KYY[Naz//2,:].min()
kend   = KYY[Naz//2,:].max()

KYq = np.linspace(kstart, kend, int(Nrg)) # query points, create a uniformly sampled points

S_st = np.zeros((len(KYY), len(KYq)), dtype = 'complex_')

for i in range(Naz):
    S_st[i,:] = np.interp(KYq, KYY[i,:], S_mf[i,:],
                          left = 0, right = 0)
    
S_final =ifft2((S_st))
```

Edit: Have included the 1-d Azimuth plots which are in the range-time and azimuth frequency domain.

Close-up of the final processed image:

[image: Close-up of the final processed image]

[image: 1-d Azimuth plot]
[image: 1-d Azimuth plot]

Comment: From looking at your axes, you should probably zoom in more and then post what you get then so that we can see clearly.

Comment: You need to post 1-D plots through the targets in the azimuth dimension.

Comment: Added the close-up of the final processed image @TommyWolfheart

Comment: Added the 1-D plots along the azimuth dimension @AnonSubmitter85

Comment: You need IPR plots through the targets in the azimuth dimension, not in the azimuth frequency dimension.

Comment: And if what you uploaded is indeed the azimuth IPR then, to state the obvious, it shouldn't be compressed into a chirp. I don't have much time to debug the code but if you want a similar simulation based on range-Doppler algorithm, give me a shout.

Comment: @TommyWolfheart Yes that would be helpful thank you!